# Can we have different log files go to different indexers in Splunk?

Tags: splunk, indexer

I have a distributed Splunk deployment with 20 indexers. 
I have multiple log files to be monitored. 
I want the log file X to be indexed by indexers 1-15 and the log file Y to be indexed by indexers 16-20. 
How can this be done? Is it possible at all?

I know how to configure multiple indexers or multiple indexes. I would like to know how do I route certain indexes to one group of indexers and another set of indexes to the second group of indexers.

Comment: you create two Splunk apps that you deploy to each group respectively...

Comment: @Oerd - The number of apps that you have doesn't actually play into anything here. While it may be a handy way of organizing configuration for a mental model, for this input / index time configuration, all of the configuration you have across all enabled apps merge together to a single configuration [by the rules of global contexts](http://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/6.2.3/Admin/Wheretofindtheconfigurationfiles#Precedence_order_within_global_context:) before taking effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As described in [Splunk's Docs](http://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/6.2.3/Forwarding/Routeandfilterdatad#Route_inputs_to_specific_indexers_based_on_the_data.27s_input), What you do is you configure both groups of indexers in outputs.conf (You'd likely want to also set one or the other or some other group of indexers as a default group as well). Then in inputs.conf, you can set _TCP_ROUTING to point to one or the other groups of indexers.

Comment: Thanks but i did figure out for splunk documentation.